# setOnItemClickListener doesn't work on Fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, listener

I have a class that extends `Fragment`. I have a `ListView`. When I click on an item, it return always the same item. 
Here the row.xml of the ListView adapter.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/IdItem"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here the event:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    myTextView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.IdItem);
                    String IdItem = myTextView.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("IdItem", IdItem);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

It always returns the same IdItem, and not the choosen one.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
myTextView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.IdItem);
```

for this:

```
myTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.IdItem);
```

The rows objects of a ListView are reused in order to save memory, so you need to use the View object being sent in the onItemClick method of the ListView. This View object represents the actual clicked row inside the ListView with current child Views and values.

Comment: This is not an answere. The thread opener and all the other users who might have the same issue should learn something and not copy paste something..

Comment: You may be right, the answer could explain a little bit more, and I'll follow your advice, nevertheless, it's still and answer, and it helped the op to fix his problem. Probably most of the people would quickly understand why that change.

Comment: Yeah most of the People but not all, and why do Research of an answere to understand what fixes the Problem. Why not simply provide informations to prevent users of doing double Research if the answere is already here if you know what i mean. Now it is an answere, removed the downvote !